# If a combo box = specific text then display in text box current date

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

If a combo box = Closed, rejected or cancelled then display today's date in text box.

for example I have a combo box that has closed open rejected and cancelled. 
If someone chooses closed rejected or canceled then I need a text box to display the current date.

I tried the below code but not sure where to put it.

```
=IIf([status_box]="Closed",Date(),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be as *ControlSource* for that textbox:

```
=IIf([status_box]="Closed" Or [status_box]="Rejected" Or [status_box]="Cancelled",Date(),Null)
```

**Edit:**

Use the *AfterUpdate* of the combobox:

```vb
Dim Status As String

Status = Nz(Me![Status_box].Value)

If Status = "Closed" Or Status = "Rejected" Or Status = "Cancelled" Then
    Me!ConclusionDate.Value = Date()
Else
    Me!ConclusionDate.Value = Null
End If
```

Comment: That worked but how do I get that to link to a field in a table if put the code in the source box? I have a field called conclusion date that I need to be updated as well depending on that combo box.